# 2d platformer enemy movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been researching for at least two hours on how to make an enemy character that moves left and right on a platform without falling off. I have tried out 4 different scripts and gone through 2 youtube tutorials but I just seem to be getting errors on everything. This is my first post so please notify me if i'm doing anything wrong, thank you :).

My code is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyPatrol : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MoveSpeed;
    public bool MoveRight;
    public var velocity: Vector2;

    void Update () 
    {
        if (MoveRight) {
            public bool GetComponent<rigidbody2D>().velocity = 
              new Vector2(MoveSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        } else {
            public bool GetComponent<rigidbody2D>().velocity = 
              new Vector2(-MoveSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        }
    }
}
```

My errors:

```
Assets/Scripts/EnemyPatrol.cs(8,28): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol \`:' in class, struct, or interface member declaration  
Assets/Scripts/EnemyPatrol.cs(8,37): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol \`;' in class, struct, or interface member declaration  
Assets/Scripts/EnemyPatrol.cs(13,30): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol \`public'  
Assets/Scripts/EnemyPatrol.cs(15,30): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol \`public'
```

Comment: `public var velocity: Vector2;` is not a valid field declaration, you need to specify type and name like you did on the two immediately proceeding declarations.

Comment: Seems like you have mixed Javascript to C# code. The Vector2 velocity variable definition looks like javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution that can help you get started.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyPatrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D enemyRigidBody2D;
    public int UnitsToMove = 5;
    public float EnemySpeed = 500;
    public bool _isFacingRight;
    private float _startPos;
    private float _endPos;

    public bool _moveRight = true;


    // Use this for initialization
    public void Awake()
    {
         enemyRigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _startPos = transform.position.x;
        _endPos = _startPos + UnitsToMove;
        _isFacingRight = transform.localScale.x > 0;
    }


// Update is called once per frame
public void Update()
{

    if (_moveRight)
    {
        enemyRigidBody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right * EnemySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (!_isFacingRight)
            Flip();
    }

    if (enemyRigidBody2D.position.x >= _endPos)
        _moveRight = false;

    if (!_moveRight)
    {
        enemyRigidBody2D.AddForce(-Vector2.right * EnemySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (_isFacingRight)
            Flip();
    }
    if (enemyRigidBody2D.position.x <= _startPos)
        _moveRight = true;


}

    public void Flip()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
        _isFacingRight = transform.localScale.x > 0;
    }

}
```